# How to print the contents of a multidimensional array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, printf

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[2][2];

    arr[0][0] = 1;
    arr[0][1] = 2;
    arr[1][0] = 3;
    arr[1][1] = 4;

    printf("%d", arr[1]);
    printf("%d", arr[1][0]); 

    return 0;
}
```

The output for the above code is coming out as unsigned int.

**Output:**
`64222963`

How do I get the output as {3,4} and 3?

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about that first printf, turn up the warnings till it does. `-Wall -Wextra` is good for gcc and clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it's a string and you're using the `%s` conversion specifier, you can't print the contents of an entire array (or a row of a 2D array) in a single conversion.  To get the output you want, you will have to print each row element individually:

```
printf( "{%d, %d}\n", arr[1][0], arr[1][1] );
```

In a more general case where you have more than two elements per row, you would use a loop (ideally in its own function):

```
void dispArr( int *arr, size_t num_elements, FILE *stream)
{
  fputc( '{', stream);

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ )
    fprintf( stream, "%d%s", arr[i], 
      num_elements - i > 1 ? ", " : "}\n" );
}
```

The last bit of the `fprintf` statement basically says "output `,`  after each element except the last element, which outputs `}\n`".  In your code you'd call it as

```
dispArr( arr[1], 2, stdout );
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first printf() statement references an array (arr[1]), so it's printing out the address of the array.

Your second printf() statement prints an array element, but since you didn't include an endline ("\n") in your first printf(), it just gets added onto the end of the first printf().

Comment: Just to expand on that, there probably was a clue about that first "printf()" call in your compiler warnings with a narrative such as "warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]".